# Filling points in a grid - Forward Euler algorithm - wrong output

Tags: python, math, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I will very briefly try to explain what I'm doing to those who are less experienced with mathematics, it's really quite simple.

We are trying to fill a grid, as follows:

[image]

We find the orange point, `U(j,n+1)`, using three points in a row below it, `U(j-1,n), U(j,n), U(j,n+1)`

Where the value of U in the entire bottom row is given, and is periodic. So theoretically we can fill this entire grid.

The formula for calculating the orange point is:

```
U(j,n+1) = U(j,n) + (delta_t / (2 * delta_x)) * (U(j+1,n) - U(j-1,n))
```

We can write it easily as a system of linear equations as follows:

[image]

And now we just repeat this process of multiplying by this matrix (iterating through the time variable) as much as we want. That's a simple way to numerically approximate a solution to a partial differential equation.

I wrote a code that does this, and then I compare my final row, to the known solution of the differential equation.

This is the code

```
import math
import numpy

def f(x):
    return math.cos(2 * math.pi * x)


def solution(x, t):
    return math.cos(2 * math.pi * (x + t))


# setting everything up
N = 16

Lambda = 10 ** (-20)
Delta_x = 1/(N+1)
Delta_t = Lambda * Delta_x * Delta_x
t_f = 5
v_0 = numpy.zeros((N, 1))

# Filling first row, initial condition was given
for i in range(N):
    v_0[i, 0] = f(i * Delta_x)

# Create coefficient matrix
M = numpy.zeros((N, N))
for i in range(N):
    M[i, i - 1] = -Delta_t / (2 * Delta_x)
    M[i, i] = 1
    M[i, (i + 1) % N] = Delta_t / (2 * Delta_x)

# start iterating through time
v_i = v_0
for i in range(math.floor(t_f / Delta_t) - 1):
    v_i = numpy.dot(M, v_i)

v_final = v_i
if (Delta_t * math.ceil(t_f / Delta_t) != t_f): #we don't reach t_f exactly using Delta_t
    v_final = (1/2) * (v_i + numpy.dot(M, v_i))

u = numpy.zeros(v_final.shape)
for i in range(N):
    u[i, 0] = solution(i * Delta_x, t_f)

for x in range(v_final.shape[0]):
    print (v_final[x], u[x])
```

theoretically speaking, I should be able to find lambda small enough such that v_final and the known solution, u, will be very similar.

But I can't. No matter how small I make lambda, how finde I make the grid, I seem to converge to something incorrect. They aren't close.

I can't for the life of me figure out the problem.
Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Stability limit for Euler equations is well known.  A Fourier analysis will tell you the limit quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `Delta_x = 1.0/N`, as you divide the interval into `N` cells.

You get `N+1` points on the grid from `u[0]` to `u[N]`, but as per boundary condition `u[N]=u[0]`, there you also only use an array of length `N` to hold all the node values.

Per your given formulas you have `gamma = dt/(2*dx)`, thus the reverse computation should be `dt = gamma*2*dx` or in your variable names

```
Delta_t = Lambda * 2 * Delta_x
```

Or you are aiming at the error of the method which is `O(dt, dx²)` so that it would make sense to have `dt = c*dx^2`, but not with a ridiculous factor like of `c=1e-20`, if you want the time discretization error small against the space discretization error, `c=0.1` or `c=0.01` should be sufficient.

---

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.cos(2 * np.pi * x)

def solution(x, t):
    return f(x + t)


# setting everything up
N_x = 16

Lambda = 1e-2
Delta_x = 1./N_x
Delta_t = Lambda * Delta_x * Delta_x
t_f = 5
N_t = int(t_f/Delta_t+0.5); t_f = N_t*Delta_t

# Filling first row, initial condition was given
x = np.arange(0,N_x,1) * Delta_x
v_0 = f(x)

# Create coefficient matrix
M = np.zeros((N_x, N_x))
for i in range(N_x):
    M[i, i - 1] = -Delta_t / (2 * Delta_x)
    M[i, i] = 1
    M[i, (i + 1) % N_x] = Delta_t / (2 * Delta_x)

# start iterating through time
v_i = v_0[:]
for i in range(N_t):
    v_i = np.dot(M, v_i)

v_final = v_i

u = solution(x, t_f)

for vx, ux in zip(v_final, u):
    print (vx, ux)
```

---

The Euler method is also not the most precise method, the expected error is in the range `exp(L*t_f)*dx^2 = e^5/N_x^2=0.58` for `N_x=16` where `L=1` was taken as approximate Lipschitz constant. Now if you increase to `N_x=50` this error estimate reduces to `0.06` which is also visible in the results.

---

The `t` exact solution of the `x` discretized problem is `cos(2*pi*(x+c*t))` where `c=sin(2*pi*dx)/(2*pi*dx)`. If you compare against that formula, the errors should be really small of size `O(dt)`.

Comment: Hey LutzL. I'm going for dt = lambda dx^2. lambda = 0.1 and 0.01 Don't yield correct results. Maybe it's due to the point you said about N. I will try and fix it.

Comment: Euler is also not the most precise method, the expected error is in the range `exp(L*t_f)*dx^2 = e^5/N^2=0.58` for `N=16`. Now if you increase to `N=50` this error estimate reduces to `0.06` which is also visible in the results.

Comment: I made some revisions that you suggested, but I still don't get a good approximation for N = 16. It's worth noting that when I run the code you posted, I still don't get a good approximation at t_f = 5.

Comment: You should get results that are consistent among themselves for constant `N_x` when you decrease `dt`. But they will be far away from the exact continuous solution as there you add in each step also the space discretization error which then gets magnified via Grönwall lemma.

Comment: My results for N = 16 and t_f = 5 are consistent as I decrease dt. Consistently bad. The approximated function does not vary much as I make dt smaller, but it is not at all to the continuous solution. Is it not a bug? What's the point of this algorithm if it doesn't approximate well? Sorry for ignorance, I am still learning.

Comment: To re-iterate: In each step you make a discretization error of size `dt+dx^2` relative to the exact solution. This gets magnified to the next step with a factor `(1+L*dt)~exp(L*dt)`. In the sum of this compound error interest accumulation you get an error of size `(dt+dx²)*(exp(L*t_f)-1)/L`. Reducing `dt` does not change the error part contributed via `dx²`. And `e^5=148.5` is a significant factor for small `N_x`.